# extract() error with customer orders in php

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I am having problems with my customer order php file I am creating.

I am trying to select the stockID from my Stock table and the userID and orderID from my Orders table.

This will then be inserted into my Ordered_Items table.

It works fine with 1 item being ordered, however when multiple items are ordered it shows the following error:

Warning: extract(): First argument should be an array in /home/k0900863/www/Coursework/order.php on line 101

```
foreach ($cart as $id=>$no)
   {
      $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE stockID='$id'");
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row); // Line 101
      $result2=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(orderID) FROM Orders WHERE userID='$userID'");
      $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
      extract($row2);
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO Ordered_Items (stockID, units, orderID) 
                   VALUES ('$id', '$no', '$orderID')");   
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) can return `FALSE` instead of an `Array`. Better use this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE stockID='$id'");
if ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  extract($row); // Line 101
  // Rest of your code ...
}
```

See as well: [`extract`](http://php.net/extract).

Answer (score 0):

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

will (by default) return an array with both numeric and associative keys.

This means that extract($row) will try to create variables like

> $1

as well as

> $columnname

and $1 is an invalid name for a variable because the varname is a numeric

Likewise, for $row2, you have "MAX(orderID)" which means extract will try to create a variable called

> $MAX(orderID)

Either use the second argument for mysql_fetch_array()

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

or use

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```